# Jazz record shops/labels

Tags: jazz, record-labels

Does anyone know of any (I guess) independent jazz record shops/labels anywhere in the world, that you are able to contact to look for records and information and what have you. I know, of course that you can buy from Amazon, eBay and all that, but if you contact them for information (on other records, or artists etc.) they tend to be of little help.

Also, if I can, I would like to shop from independents (even if they have a store front on Amazon).

I am looking for places that I can contact via email, ask for something and they send it to me, or will contact me of they come across it. So, I am hoping someone is like "Yea, the guy down the road from me does that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if they would do this for you, but I would check with Honest Jon's based out of London. They seem like the kind of outfit that might do that over the internet.  Or else just start trying to ring up desperate mom and pop shops that you find on the internet.

http://honestjons.com/

mail@honestjons.com